# Is serverpilot making a ssh connection without ssh key, despite password authentication is disabled?

Tags: ssh, server

Following the basic instructions to secure the server, I took the following steps:

1. added a ssh-key
2. disabled password authentication
3. disabled rootlogin
4. created another user with sudo

As an another user I've no problem in accessing my server through terminal.

Now, I've also added my server on serverpilot [serverpilot.io], and my curiosity lies in the fact that without ssh key the server can't be accessed then how the user serverpilot is accessing the server with password and without sshkey which is not shared with serverpilot.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [su] or [unix.se].

Comment: Ok @Kenster, it seems I like stack overflow too much ;) , will follow your advice.